# Conditional Formatting with percentage in one cell

Tags: excel, formatting, cell, conditional-formatting

I would like to create in excel condition formatting with percentage.

Here's what I have already (edited)

[[image]
[[image]
[[image]
[[image]
But I would like the separate my cell:
1) if value is less than cell value then background is green
1) if value is greaterthan cell value then background is red

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to format cell A7 based on the comparison of A7's value with the value in A1. Is that correct??

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll start over.

in your screenshot, cell A7 does not have a value. therefore it is not greater than A1, therefore the green formatting rule is applied.

If you enter a value into cell A7, then that value can be used in the comparison of the conditional formatting rule. If A1 has the value 56% and you enter 57% into A7, then A7 will turn red.

[image]

If the value in cell A7 is less than 56% (and that includes the case where the cell is empty!!), then the green format will be applied.

[image]

If that is not what you want to achieve, then please edit your question and clarify.

Or do you want to set the color of A7 based on the value in A1, and if A1 is greater than something, then apply a format? In that case, please clarify what you want to compare the value in A1 WITH, because then we're back to the logic flaw in your original question. You cannot use the value in A1 and compare whether it's greater or less than the value in A1. That does not make sense.

Comment: Okay, IT can be two cells

Comment: I've changed it, but the results is the same. I have one solid color, not separate. (e.g. 57% should be blue and 43 % should be orange)

Comment: Yeah it's the same. But I would like to have another result. I would like to have one cell with 2 color (e.g. 57% should be green and 43 % should be red)

Comment: I know Excel  but I asked for another solution.

Comment: I edited my answer. If that is not what you want to achieve, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> I would like to have one cell with 2 color (e.g. 57% should be green and 43 % should be red)

...it sounds like you're looking for something quite different from the original question.  If you'd like your cell to have two colors, the proportion of which changes based on the value of the cell, you can use a databar and a set background.

Here, the background is red, and the databar is green.  The length of the databar changes based on the value of the cell.

[image]

Is this what you're after?